# Javascript DOM - Set cell attribute to image?

Tags: javascript, image, attributes, setattribute

I have a small predicament. I'm dynamically trying to set a table cell html to an image, based on SQL response.. My method below just isn't working..

> var data = document.createElement("td");

```
if  (response.getElementsByTagName('status')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue=='unread') {

    data.setAttribute('id', 'emailunread');
    data.innerHTML="<img src ='/img/unread.png' width='64' height='64'>";
    else {

    data.setAttribute('id', 'emailread'); }
    data = '<img src="img/read.png>'; }
```

Any ideas which one I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your `if` statement block with a closing curly brace.

```
if (response.getElementsByTagName('status')[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue=='unread') {

    data.setAttribute('id', 'emailunread');
    data.innerHTML="<img src ='/img/unread.png' width='64' height='64'>";
} else {

    data.setAttribute('id', 'emailread');
    data = '<img src="img/read.png>'; 
}
```

Additionally, as Bergi has pointed out, you are overwriting the variable that contains your DOM element with some HTML in the `else` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the [`innerHTML` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) in the last line. Instead of overwriting the variable with a string:

```
data = '<img src="img/read.png>';
```

you want

```
data.innerHTML = '<img src="img/read.png>';
```

Also, your blocks seem not to be closed properly, you've got an additional `}` in the second-to-last line. Not sure whether any of these is just a c&p mistake or your actual problem.

Btw, you should assign the value of `response.getElementsByTagName('status')` to a variable and loop over that (I assume that `i` is an iteration variable), instead of querying the DOM each time.

Comment: I assumed that i'd get quicker results with a simple innerHTML line rather than put the result in a variable. It's strange as it still returns an empty cell..

Comment: Could you show us the whole code, maybe in a demo on jsfiddle.net or the like?